# How to hide a table row that has an empty value, the transpose mysql

Tags: php, html

I have a table from the database and I try to change the display field of row into columns, and I wanted to try to hide rows that have a null value.

My tabel

```
|   no  |   android |   apple   |   windows |   java    |   symbian |   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1   |     10    |    20     |   50      |     0     |      0    |
```

results transpose

```
|    OS Phone   |   Value   |
-----------------------------   
|   android     |     50    |
|   apple       |     30    |
|   windows     |     10    |   
|   java        |     0     |
|   symbian     |     0     |
```

which are expected

```
|    OS Phone   |   Value   |
-----------------------------   
|   android     |     50    |
|   apple       |     30    |
|   windows     |     10    |
```

my php

```
<?php       
foreach($get_os as $key => $row) {
    foreach($row as $field => $value) { 
        $get_field[$field][] = $value;
    }
}

echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>\n";
    echo "<thead>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "\t<td>OS Phone</td>\n" ; 
            echo "\t<td>Value</td>\n";  
        echo "</tr>";
    echo "</thead>";
    echo "<thead>"; 
        foreach ($get_field as $key => $values) {
            echo "<tr>\n";                  
                echo "\t<td>" . $key . "</td>\n" ; 
                foreach ($values as $cell) {
                    if($cell > 0 ){     
                        echo "\t<td>" . $cell . "</td>\n"; 
                    }   
                }                       
            echo "</tr>\n"; 
        }
    echo "</thead>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the value before printing the row

```
foreach ($get_field as $key => $values) 
        {
           $line .= "<tr>\n";                  
                $line .= "\t<td>" . $key . "</td>\n" ; 
                foreach ($values as $cell) 
                {
                    if($cell > 0 ){     
                        echo $line."\t<td>" . $cell . "</td>\n</tr>\n"; 
                    }   
                }                       
            }
```

Comment: it's same just `$cell` hide but `$key` not hide

Comment: I have made some edits. This gets your desired results